# How to place "deleted" objects into an array?

Tags: php, arrays

How do i create an array where deconstructed or deleted objects are saved in. I wrote the code below but it doesnt work.The goal is to add usernames of deconstructed users into the array deletedUsers.

```
//Class User
class User
{
    //User attributes
    public $firstname;
    public $lastname;
    protected $username;
    protected $registerdate;
    public $deletedUsers = array();

    //Constructor
    public function __construct($firstname, $lastname)
    {
        $this->firstname = $firstname;
        $this->lastname = $lastname;
        $this->username = "$firstname.$lastname" . rand(1, 100);
        $this->registrdate = date("d.m.Y");
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        $this->deletedUsers[] = $this->username;
        return implode(", ",  $this->deletedUsers);
        echo "User has been deleted";
    }
  
    public function getInfo()
    {
        return $this->firstname . " " . $this->lastname . " " . $this->username . " " . $this->registredate;
    }

    public function getDeletedUsers()
    {
        $dUsers = implode(", ",  $this->deletedUsers);
        return $dUsers;
    }
}

    $user1 = new User("John", "Smith");
    echo $iser1->getInfo();
    echo "<br>";
    unset($user1);
    echo $user1->getDeletedUsers();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static properties can be used for this purpose

```
class User
{
    //User attributes
    public $firstname;
    public $lastname;
    protected $username;
    protected $registrdate;
    protected static $deletedUsers = [];

    //Constructor
    public function __construct($firstname, $lastname)
    {
        $this->firstname = $firstname;
        $this->lastname = $lastname;
        $this->username = "$firstname.$lastname" . rand(1, 100);
        $this->registrdate = date("d.m.Y");
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        self::$deletedUsers[] = $this->username;
        echo "User has been deleted";
    }

    public static function getDeletedUsers()
    {
        return implode(", ",  self::$deletedUsers);
    }

    public function getInfo()
    {
        return $this->firstname . " " . $this->lastname . " " . $this->username . " " . $this->registrdate;
    }
}

$user1 = new User("John", "Smith");
echo $user1->getInfo();
echo "<br>";
unset($user1);
echo User::getDeletedUsers();
```

Answer (score 0):

The fourth line, `unset($user1);` is destroying the User object you created, so you can't display `deletedUsers()` from that object. What you want instead is a `Users` class that contains all users, deleted and active.

```
$user1 = new User("John", "Smith");
echo $user1->getInfo();
echo "<br>";
unset($user1);
echo $user1->getDeletedUsers();
```

Comment: yes that would be much simpler, but this is my task. "Create a deconstructor for the class that saves the usernames of deleted users in an array". Is this not possible?